# Python Retaining Column Value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this (index, Place):

```
0 California*
1 LA
2 San Diego
3 Oakland
4 Washington*
5 Seattle
6 Tacoma
```

The values in Place that are states are marked with an asterisk, so I'd like to create a new column and fill it in with the state value. I want to assign the value for state based on any row that has an asterisk and then fill it for all the subsequent rows until a new row comes with a new value. In SAS, this would be done with a retain statement, but I don't know how it works with pandas.

The output should be (index, Place, State):

```
0 California* California
1 LA          California
2 San Diego   California
3 Oakland     California
4 Washington* Washington
5 Seattle     Washington
6 Tacoma      Washington
```

etc.

What's a simple and elegant way of going about this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) with mask created with [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) and [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
print (df.col.str[-1] == '*')
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
Name: col, dtype: bool

df['new'] = df.col.str[:-1].where(df.col.str[-1] == '*').ffill()
print (df)
           col         new
0  California*  California
1           LA  California
2    San Diego  California
3      Oakland  California
4  Washington*  Washington
5      Seattle  Washington
6       Tacoma  Washington
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Series.str.extract()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method in conjunction with [Series.ffill()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
In [236]: df['State'] = df.Place.str.extract(r'([^\*]+)\*', expand=False).ffill()

In [237]: df
Out[237]:
         Place       State
0  California*  California
1           LA  California
2    San Diego  California
3      Oakland  California
4  Washington*  Washington
5      Seattle  Washington
6       Tacoma  Washington
```

Answer (score 0):

***creative answer***

```
df.iloc[:, 0].str.split('*').str[::-1] \
  .apply(pd.Series).replace('', np.nan).bfill(1).ffill()
```

[image]

---

***serious answer***
uses `extract` like @MaxU.  Difference is that I'm using insert.  Nothing notably better, just different.

```
df.insert(df.shape[1], 'State', df.iloc[:, 0].str.extract('(.*)\*'))
df = df.ffill()

df
```

[image]